# Inserting Javascript based on Ruby If Statement

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to trigger a bootstrap modal based on conditions about the current user.  Essentially, to do anything in the page the user is accessing, they need to have created a hotel in the system.  If they haven't, I want a modal to pop up with the creation form.  Currently, I have:

```
 <%= unless current_user.hotels.exists? 
    "<script>
       $('#createhotelModal').modal('toggle') 
     </script>"
     end    
    %>
```

Which simply inserts the  as text.  Trying to next a <%= javascript_tag do %> command doesn't work with the controller throwing various errors.  Is this the smart way to do it, or should I just create a completely separate page and use the controller to send people to the correct page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow advice listed in this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript)

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $('#createhotelModal').modal('toggle')
<% end %>
```